# How to construct a clone of an `Rc` datastructure on another thread with only one copy

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a datastructure like this:

```rust
use std::{thread, rc::Rc};

#[derive(Clone)]
struct HugeAmoutOfData {}  // imagine this being large :)

struct Node {
    foo: Vec<Rc<Node>>,
    bar: HugeAmoutOfData,
}
```

**for (legitimately measured) performance reasons, I don't want to use Arc because lots of these things get moved around a lot.**

---

The *problem* now arises when I need to create a deep clone of such a Node structure on a second thread. Because `Rc` isn't `Send`, I currently do the following madness:

```
struct BoxedNode {
    foo: Vec<Box<BoxedNode>>,
    bar: HugeAmoutOfData, 
}

impl From<&Rc<Node>> for Box<BoxedNode> { /* ... */ }
impl From<&Box<BoxedNode>> for Rc<Node> { /* ... */ }
   

fn main() {
    let foo = Rc::new(Node { foo: Default::default(), bar: HugeAmoutOfData{}});
    let foo_box = Box::<BoxedNode>::from(&foo); // deep clone 1
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let _foo_copy = Rc::<Node>::from(&foo_box); // deep clone 2
    }).join().unwrap();
    let _bar = foo; // keep using foo here
}
```

(Link to full demo [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f76daf5d47334dd5a91efeacadad2686))

---

How can I avoid the second deep clone, considering that there is no way to convert between `Box<T>` <--> `Rc<T>` that reuses the allocation?

To be clear, the goal is the `_foo_copy`, which is an `Rc<Node>` again. Everything in between, including the whole `Box` nightmare can be changed.

It is also worth mentioning that the Node structure is acyclic (but not a tree) in nature, if that makes it easier.

Comment: Have you tried `Arc<Vec<Node>>` instead of `Vec<Arc<Node>>`? Would require fewer locks/unlocks at the expense of longer wait times.

Comment: @BallpointBen: I think you missed the part where I mention that I don't want to use Arc for performance reasons :)

Comment: What "performance reasons"? `Arc` is pretty quick if used properly.

Comment: Are you sure that deep copy is less expensive than using `Arc`? Anyway, is using unsafe code okay?

Comment: Sometimes Rust steers towards designs that are like `Arc<Vec<Node>>` and instead of storing actual references, you store vector indexes.

Comment: @tadman: millions of these node references In a vector get copied around many times. The ~30x overhead of Arc over Rc on every copy is just not acceptable for my application.

Comment: It honestly sounds like you need to apply some `Cow` here.

Comment: I don't think `Arc` has a 30x overhead over `Rc`, not even close (although I admit I didn't measure), at least if there is no atomic contention. If there is atomic contention, you can still use `Arc` but give each thread its own deep copy of the data. This way, you avoid the `Box` step, with no unsafe code.

Comment: I'm thinking you could call `make_mut` to ensure the local `Rc` is unique, then it *might* be sound to unsafely send it to another thread. Encapsulate this behavior in a wrapper type. This should keep it to one underlying copy.

Comment: Btw, are you sure that “there is no way to convert between Box<T> <--> Rc<T> that reuses the allocation”? `Box<T>: Into<Rc<T>>` and I think this might reuse the allocation?

Comment: You might be able to replace `Rc` with `SendRc` from the [sendable crate](https://crates.io/crates/sendable). That type is like `Rc`, but can be safely sent between threads (the readme explains why this is sound, and what steps you need to take at run-time to make it happen). In your case you could first deep-clone the collection of `Rc` and then send it to a different thread.

Comment: Also, if you don't use interior mutability, replacing `Rc` with `Arc` *should* work. Access to the contents of an `Arc` is just as fast as that of `Rc`, it's only if you frequently clone/drop the Arc that it becomes slower (and even that might be acceptable when uncontended). It's when you use `Rc<RefCell<T>>` that `Arc` is a tougher sell, since it requires you to change `RefCell` to `Mutex`, which is more heavyweight.

Comment: @drewtato That's exactly what [my deleted answer](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b4ed30bcb9fb93ee76b662431267d454) does, but it doesn't work because he has nested `Rc`s. `make_mut` will do a shallow clone only. The wrapper I wrote won't be `Send` because `T` isn't `Send` as it contains other `Rc`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to solve this, but perhaps the simplest (aside from using `Arc` anyway, as others have mentioned in the comments) is wrapping an `Rc` up in a struct that implements `Send`.  In order for this to be safe, the inner `T` needs to be `Send` and we need to know for certain that the `Rc` is completely independent (has a strong count of 1 and a weak count of 0).

The latter is simple enough to take care of with `Rc::make_mut()` but the former is trickier.  In your case, `Node` isn't `Send` because it further contains `Rc`s itself.

What we need is a way to declare that a type is "send if unshared" and then provide a means to "unshare" it recursively.  We can declare our own trait for this concept easily enough.

```
pub unsafe trait SendIfUnshared {
    fn unshare(&mut self);
}
```

The contract of this trait is that, after calling `SendIfUnshared::unshare()` on a value, that value is effectively `Send` *until it is read from or written to again.*  We have to disallow reads because `Rc`s can be cloned by a shared reference.
Moving the value is the only operation that preserves its `Send`-ness.

We mark this trait `unsafe` because an incorrect implementation can lead to soundness issues.

The implementation for `Rc<T>` is straightforward enough:

```
unsafe impl<T> SendIfUnshared for Rc<T>
where T: SendIfUnshared + Clone
{
    fn unshare(&mut self) {
        Rc::make_mut(self).unshare();
    }
}
```

Now we can implement this on `Node` (which must be modified to implement `Clone` for `Rc::make_mut()` to work).

```
unsafe impl SendIfUnshared for Node {
    fn unshare(&mut self) {
        for i in &mut self.foo {
            i.unshare();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note that this is only sound if `HugeAmountOfData` is `Send`.**  The contract of `SendIfUnshared` requires *you* to verify this before implementing the trait.

We can make this implementation more safe and future-proof against changes that might make the rest of the struct non-`Send`.  First, we make a function that asserts that its argument is `Send`:

```
fn assert_send(_: &impl Send) {}
```

Then we destructure `self` in our `SendIfUnshared` implementation.  This will cause a compile-time error if the fields of `Node` are altered later, which will remind us to update this implementation.  Then, any destructured field that we don't handle specially will receive an "unused variable" warning.  We should pass these fields to `assert_send`.

This way, any way the struct changes later should be caught in one way or another, and we can verify that the changes don't introduce any unexpected "un-`Send`-ness."

```
unsafe impl SendIfUnshared for Node {
    fn unshare(&mut self) {
        let Node { foo, bar } = self;

        for i in foo {
            i.unshare();
        }

        assert_send(bar);
    }
}
```

Now we can create a wrapper using this trait to make a `SendIfUnshared` value `Send`.

```
pub struct SendableSendIfUnshared<T>(T);

unsafe impl<T: SendIfUnshared> Send for SendableSendIfUnshared<T> {}

impl<T> SendableSendIfUnshared<T> {
    pub fn into_inner(self) -> T {
        self.0
    }
}

impl<T: SendIfUnshared> SendableSendIfUnshared<T> {
    pub fn new(mut inner: T) -> Self {
        inner.unshare();
        Self(inner)
    }
}
```

As a final ergonomic change, we can extend the trait to provide a conversion method.  (Properly, this should be done with a new trait and a blanket implementation, but I've omitted it for the sake of brevity as this answer is already getting quite long.)

```
pub unsafe trait SendIfUnshared {
    fn unshare(&mut self);
    
    fn into_sendable(self) -> SendableSendIfUnshared<Self>
    where Self: Sized
    {
        SendableSendIfUnshared::new(self)
    }
}
```

Now, given a `Node` or an `Rc<Node>`, you should be able to call `the_node.into_sendable()` to obtain a completely independent `Node` inside of a wrapper that can be sent to another thread.  You can then invoke `.into_inner()` on the wrapper from the other thread to extract the contained value, which removes the `Send` capability from it.

([Complete demo on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=145a9dfa71063c2c1449e462e131acd4))

---

Be very careful with the wrapper, as certain modifications that would seem to make sense could compromise its soundness.  For example, implementing `Deref<Target = T>` on the wrapper to provide easy access to the inner value is unsound because one of the contained `Rc`s could be cloned, which would make it unsound to send the wrapper anymore, but nothing would prevent you from doing that.

Even implementing `Debug` opens the door to soundness issues, as a malicious `Debug` implementation could clone an `Rc`.

Both of these implementations violate the contract of `SendIfShared` because they allow reading the contained `T`.

The wrapper's interface is minimal on purpose, and it ensures that the only way to read from or write to the contained `T` is to discard the `Send` wrapper first.